# Running a cron job at 2:30 AM everyday

Tags: cron

How to configure a cron job to run every night at 2:30? I know how to make it run at 2, but not 2:30.

Comment: Beware: in many jurisdictions that switch from standard time to daylight time, the local time hour between 02:00 and 03:00 *does not exist* on the "spring forward" switchover day, and happens twice on the "fall back" day. Weird but true. If your machine's OS is configured for a local time zone in one of those jurisdictions (most of the USA, for example) your job won't run on the spring forward day, and will run twice on the fall back day. Use UTC, or avoid the strange hour.

Comment: For double checking, this site (https://crontab.guru/) is very helpful, and I also found GitHub CoPilot would add a comment stating what the cron entry meant, which was a nice way to double check.

Answer (score 613, accepted):

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
30 2 * * * /your/command
```

Answer (score 184):

1. To edit:

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```
2. Add this command line:

   ```
   30 2 * * * /your/command
   ```

   - Crontab Format:

     > MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD
   - Format Meanings and Allowed Value:
   - `MIN     Minute field    0 to 59`
   - `HOUR    Hour field      0 to 23`
   - `DOM     Day of Month    1-31`
   - `MON     Month field     1-12`
   - `DOW     Day Of Week     0-6`
   - `CMD     Command     Any command to be executed.`
3. Restart cron with latest data:

   ```
   service crond restart
   ```

Comment: use "service cron restart" for ubuntu

Answer (score 80):

As seen in the other answers, the syntax to use is:

```bash
  30 2 * * * /your/command
# ^  ^
# |   hour
# minute
```

Following the crontab standard format:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

It is also useful to use [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru/) to check crontab expressions.

The expressions are added into `crontab` using `crontab -e`. Once you are done, save and exit (if you are using `vi`, typing `:x` does it). The good think of using this tool is that if you write an invalid command you are likely to get a message prompt on the form:

```
$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.tNt1NL/crontab":7: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)
```

If you have further problems with crontab not running you can check [Debugging crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) or [Why is crontab not executing my PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17362250/1983854).

Comment: crontab.guru is a very useful resource

Answer (score 9):

An easy way to write cron is to use the online cron [generator](http://crontab-generator.org/)
It will generate the line for you. One thing to note is that if you wish to run it each day (not just weekdays) you need to highlight all the days.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the all above mentioned great answers, check the https://crontab.guru/ - a useful online resource for checking your crontab syntax.

What you get is human readable representation of what you have specified.

See the examples below:

- [30 2 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#30_2_*_*_*) (answer of this question)
- [@daily](https://crontab.guru/#@daily)
- [59 23 31 12 *](https://crontab.guru/#59_23_31_12_*)

Answer (score 1):

30 2 * * * wget https://www.yoursite.com/your_function_name

The first part is for setting cron job and the next part to call your function.

Answer (score 1):

30 2 * * *  **Every Day at 2:30 Am**

30-31 2 * * *  **Every Day at 2:30 -31 am**

Along with he answers its important to understand the cron expressions , i face a lot of difficulty in understanding .
But an intuitive way to understand [is given here](https://thelinuxterminal.com/cron-expression-generator/) .