# How to call a website everyday at the same time?

Tags: php, date, curl, time

I just want to call a website (curl) everyday at 5:00 pm for example.

Any idea about how to do this? I'd not like to use database if it's possible.

I've seen this post but doesn't help me because what I want is to do it with code. The script would be in my server and this would be the pseudocode:

-Check what time is it
-If it's 5:00 am call a website through curl

Comment: If your server is linux, use a [cron](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14710257/697370)

Comment: I don't have access to my server's shell. It's from one.com

Comment: move to a host that supports the features you require

Comment: Is not there any other way to do this without a cron job?