# How to Create Django Application Backup Automatically

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have developed a web application in `Python` and `Django` and need to back up the data daily. Currently, `Postgres` is used as DBMS.

To perform the backup I discovered the `django-dbbackup` module, but to use it, I need to run the command `python manage.py dbbackup`.

How do I automatically back up every day at a certain time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Linux set up a cron job by following this example: [Running a cron job at 2:30 AM everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14710257/7838574)

On Windows is similar setup a schedule task using their wizard.

The command you’ll want to use is

```
python manage.py dbbackup
```