# Running PHP script from cron

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am trying to run a PHP script through a `cronjob`. I already did this hundred of times, but now it's not working and I cannot figure out why.

I created a script called `update_db.php` in `/var/www/html/` When I run the script by hand:

```
php /var/www/html/update_db.php
```

everything works fine. When I put this into a `cronjob`, it does nothing. My cronjob:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/update_db.php
```

I tried to put a bash script in front of it that calls the PHP script, but, again, it only works when calling by hand, not from a cron.

There are no errors in the syslog. Also no mail in `/var/mail`. I restarted cron already, but no effect.

I use ubuntu 14.04.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17362250/ for some ideas about what can be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is `* * * * * php /var/www/html/update_db.php` not working? You shouldn't need to use `/usr/bin/php`.

Also, check to make sure crons are running on your current system and that your files/directories have the appropriate permissions to be run by the cron.

Comment: Do you have any other crons currently running on your system? If so, are they running properly?

Comment: Yes. I just tested another (test) database script and that works fine. Leaves me puzzled even more

Comment: It still sounds like a permissions issue to me. Have you changed the owner/group to the cron user and tried chmod to 777? Obviously you wouldn't want that in production, but if we can get that to work it's a place to start dialing back.

Answer (score 0):

CRON "should" be logging.
Check the /var/log/cron, looking for your script errorrs or otherwise.

some implementations of cron need a full on restart - I have personanlly never had this issue, but I know fellow admins who have spent far too much time chasing fault, when a simple restart did the trick.