# php cron job not running

Tags: php, linux, cron

```
root@xx:/var/www/test# which php
/usr/bin/php
```

---

```
root@xx:/var/www/test# ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 09:37 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root 4096 Nov 13 15:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  153 Nov 14 09:35 test.php
```

This is my `test.php` file:

```
<?php
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
```

And this is the output of `crontab -l`:

```
#this is ok
* * * * * touch /tmp/hello
#this only creates an empty php_result.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/test/test.php > /tmp/php_result.log
```

---

```
root@xx:/var/www/test# php -v
PHP 5.4.34-0+deb7u1 (cli) (built: Oct 20 2014 08:50:30)
```

The cron job will not run, and the problem is with php. If i run the file manually, all works well.

```
php test.php
```

Related question: [Why is crontab not executing my PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397469/why-is-crontab-not-executing-my-php-script).

Comment: What if you provide the full path of your file in `$my_file`, in `test.php`?

Comment: @fedorqui It works. It is normal the need of the full path?

Comment: Have you added blank newline at end of crontab?

Comment: @MateuszNowak yes. I have a blank line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use full paths in your scripts. Otherwise, `cron` won't know where is that file.

so instead of

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
```

use

```
$my_file = '/path/to/file.txt';
```

Probably you were getting `file.txt` stored somewhere in `/`.

Note `crontab` runs in a limited environment, so it cannot assume anything regarding to paths. That's why you also have to provide the full path of `php`, etc.

From [Troubleshooting common issues with cron jobs](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1588/Troubleshooting+common+issues+with+cron+jobs):

> Using relative paths. If your cron job is executing a script of some
>   kind, you must be sure to use only absolute paths inside that script.
>   For example, if your script is located at /path/to/script.phpand
>   you're trying to open a file called file.php in the same directory,
>   you cannot use a relative path such as fopen(file.php). The file must
>   be called from its absolute path, like this: fopen(/path/to/file.php).
>   This is because cron jobs do not necessarily run from the directory in
>   which the script is located, so all paths must be called specifically.