# Cron not running scripts on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a set of scripts (PHP Symfony2) which should execute via cron, but some are not correctly executed.

Example of call :

```
* * * * * php /var/www/admin/app/console notification:send --env=prod
```

I saw execution of each scripts by using `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`
but when checking output by using `>>/var/log/cron*.log` I don't see any output or errors.

If I run scripts manually, all is OK.
The server is under Ubuntu (Digital Ocean)
Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Give a read to [Why is crontab not executing my PHP script?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17362250/1983854)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solved. I have to use php5 -f ...

Answer (score 0):

When you run your command directly in bash, does it give output/errors?

When you say you used `>>/var/log/cron*.log` do you mean you put that at the end of your cron line?  There was absolutely no output in the file?

Try a line like this, so that you get error output in the log file as well:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/admin/app/console notification:send --env=prod >> /var/log/cron*.log 2>&1
```

Or alternatively, try this to get an e-mail of any output/errors when it runs:

```
MAILTO=youremail@example.com
* * * * * php /var/www/admin/app/console notification:send --env=prod
```

There are edge issues where things work differently when run by cron vs run by user, so compare results with your manual run, add in debugging/verbose output statements to your script and consider permissions and environmental issues if you find it halting at a particular line.

Comment: directly in bash, there is no errors.
I even setup a code within my script to log execution into database. Execution are saved just when I run command manually and not via cron (even commands which effectively works)...

Comment: When logging with >>/var/log/cron.log  I have : PDOException, could not find driver

Comment: Excellent @Yohann, glad to hear it!  If you're able, create that as an answer and then mark it; will help others out.